# gsub inside function with mutate called in dplyr chain gives error

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, gsub

I have the following example data (the real data contains other columns with both numeric and character variables):

```
structure(list(AM = structure(1:20, .Label = c("AMP_R", "AZI_R", 
"CHL_R", "CIP_R", "COL_R", "ERY_R", "ETP_R", "F.C_R", "FEP_R", 
"FOT_R", "FOX_R", "GEN_R", "IMI_R", "MERO_R", "NAL_R", "STR_R", 
"SULFA_R", "T.C_R", "TAZ_R", "TET_R"), class = "factor")), .Names = "AM", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried to create a function that will detect whether or not a column in a data frame contains variables with the ending "_R". If they do, it will remove this ending and proceed with renaming the variables to full names, accoring to a conversion table. If the "_R" ending is not present, it will just convert the names directly.

I have tried the following on the first part of the function:

```
library(dplyr)

convert_AM_names <- function(data, col) {
    data %>%
      mutate(col = gsub("(.*?)_R", "\\1", col))
}
```

I want to use it in a dplyr chain, like this:

```
AM <- AM %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  convert_AM_names(., AM)
```

However, when I do this, it gives the error "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Column "col" must be length 1, not 20"

I saw that similar issues have been addressed here at SO, but for most of them the solution was to use rowwise(), which doesn't seem to work here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to rename column names in a data frame or do you want to rename values within a column?

Comment: @awchisholm Values within a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an *anchor* for your regular expression that only matches when the `_R` is right at the end:

```
convert_AM_names <- function(col) {
  gsub("(.*)_R$", "\\1", col)
}

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(AM = convert_AM_names(AM))
```

Or directly - without the overhead of `convert_AM_names()`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(AM = gsub("(.*)_R$", "\\1", AM))
```

Both will yield:

```
      AM
1    AMP
2    AZI
3    CHL
4    CIP
5    COL
6    ERY
7    ETP
8    F.C
9    FEP
10   FOT
11   FOX
12   GEN
13   IMI
14  MERO
15   NAL
16   STR
17 SULFA
18   T.C
19   TAZ
20   TET
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mutate_at()` which allows you to select a column and apply a function to it.

```
AM %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = "AM", 
            .funs = gsub,
            pattern = "(.*?)_R",
            replacement = "\\1")
```

If you wanted, you could also rewrite your function:

```
convert_AM_names <- function(col) {
  gsub("(.*?)_R", "\\1", col)
}
```

And use it in `mutate_at()`:

```
AM %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = "AM", 
            .funs = convert_AM_names)
```

In both cases, the result looks like this:

```
      AM
1    AMP
2    AZI
3    CHL
4    CIP
5    COL
6    ERY
7    ETP
8    F.C
9    FEP
10   FOT
11   FOX
12   GEN
13   IMI
14  MERO
15   NAL
16   STR
17 SULFA
18   T.C
19   TAZ
20   TET
```

Comment: Be careful with the lazy operator (`.*?`). As it stands, your expression would also match [**`_Rsomejunkafterwards`**](https://regex101.com/r/tr16YH/1) which might not be what the OP wants.